# I need to know how to extend the program so that it reads and converts all input numbers until end of file on standard input

Tags: c++

I am writing code where a user will enter a roman numeral and the output will be a regular number. I have accomplished this, however I'm having trouble with the next part, which is to:

> Extend the program so that it reads and converts all input numbers until end of file on standard input. You'll probably be able to do this simply by adding an appropriate "reading loop" around the code that reads a single line.

My current code is:

```
#include<iostream>

#include<string>

using namespace std;

int value(char r){

    if(std::toupper(r) == 'I')
        return 1;
    if (std::toupper(r) == 'V')
        return 5;
    if (std::toupper(r) == 'X')
        return 10;
    if (std::toupper(r) == 'L')
        return 50;
    if (std::toupper(r) == 'C')
        return 100;
    if (std::toupper(r) == 'D')
        return 500;
    if (std::toupper(r) == 'M')
        return 1000;
    return -1;
}

int romantoArabic(string &str){
    int res = 0;
    for (int i=0; i<str.length(); i++)
    {

        int s1 = value(str[i]);
        if (i+1 < str.length())
        {

            int s2 = value(str[i+1]);
            if (s1 >= s2)
            {
                res = res + s1;
            }

            else
            {

                res = res + s2 - s1;
                i++; // Value of current symbol is

            }
        }

        else
        {
            res = res + s1;
            i++;

        }
    }

    return res;

}

int main(){
    string str;
    cout<<"";
    cin>>str;
    cout << ""<< romantoArabic(str) << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Say, for example, the user was to enter the following (BTW, this is what needs to be entered, and at the moment my code does not allow me to do):

```
i
ii
iii
iv
v
vi
vii
viii
ix
```

My output is:

```
1
```

When it should be:

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
```

Comment: Try "adding an appropriate 'reading loop' around the code that reads a single line", as the instructions say. I'm fairly sure that your teacher has covered these recently.

Comment: No they havent.

Comment: @R_Bowsy or they did and you didn't pay attention

Answer (score 1):

```
while (cin >> str) {
    cout << ""<< romantoArabic(str) << endl;
}
```